# An unexpected trailing result set was found when reading the results of a SaveChanges operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on a table which performs a custom insert and returns the Id:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ReferenceTrigger]  
ON [dbo].[Customers] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT   
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @reference varchar(6); --And set

    INSERT INTO Customers
    OUTPUT inserted.Id
    SELECT 
        --Here the original fields...
        Reference = @string
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT Id FROM Customers WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

I also configured the mapping for this entity in EFCore:

```
internal class CustomerMap : EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> b)
    {
        b.ToTable("Customers").HasKey(t => t.Id);
        b.ToTable(t => t.HasTrigger("ReferenceTrigger"));
        b.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }

    //etc...
}
```

When I call `CommitChanges()` on the db context I get the following warning:

> An unexpected trailing result set was found when reading the results of a SaveChanges operation; this may indicate that a stored procedure returned a result set without being configured for it in the EF model. Check your stored procedure definitions.

What do I need to fix to get rid of this warning?

Comment: `OUTPUT inserted.Id` -> this is a resultset `SELECT Id FROM Customers...` -> so is this. Why do you need two? Why do you even need one?

Comment: What's the point of this trigger? `OUTPUT` already returns the new ID. The second query serves no purpose. The *entire* trigger is trying to do what EF Core would do by itself - insert the data and use `OUTPUT inserted.ID` to return the IDs

Comment: I get the impression that this trigger's entire purpose is to automatically select the identity value upon insert. It's a bad idea dressed up as a convenience.

Comment: @madreflection `OUTPUT inserted.id` already returns the identity value. EF itself will use `OUTPUT` to do this, so this trigger isn't convenience, it's trying to replicate what already works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:: I'm not arguing differently. My point is that this looks like a pattern used by someone whose been using SSMS as their interface and created the trigger for their own convenience so they're not writing SELECTs on SCOPE_IDENTITY all the time. A convenience if SSMS is your world, but a bad idea as soon as you step out of it.

Comment: @madreflection more like blindly copying 20-year old articles because `OUTPUT` removed the need for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. SSMS doesn't need that either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No this is the way to do it with EF. Broken, but there it is https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12064

Comment: That refers to handling a valid trigger. The OP's code serves no valid purpose except returning `OUTPUT inserted.id`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Presumably OP's real code has other stuff it does?

Comment: @Charlieface it's broken in another serious way too - it can only handle a single row at a time. Triggers don't fire once per row though, they fire for the entire INSERT operation. EF Core will use a single query to insert all pending rows, not multiple ones. The actual query uses `MERGE` with a `source` part that contains multiple rows. This is done to ensure that all IDs are returned in the order of the rows

Comment: Looks like we still haven't found out what this trigger is for :-(

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger is returning resultsets, which is deprecated in SQL Server (will be removed in future).

EF expects a single resultset, so just do one or the other

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReferenceTrigger]  
ON [dbo].[Customers] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT   
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @reference varchar(6); --And set

    INSERT INTO Customers (columns_here)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id
    SELECT 
        --Here the original fields...
        Reference = @string
    FROM inserted;
END;
```

As it stands, [EF Core doesn't work well](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12064) with `INSTEAD OF` triggers. You should avoid them if you can.

Comment: If that's all the trigger does, it should be removed entirely. EF Core uses `OUTPUT` to get generated PK values already

Comment: Removing OUTPUT AND SELECT makes it even worse. Now I get `An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'AvvSpecialTicket.Infrastructure.AppContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

Comment: @IvanDebono remove the trigger entirely. The code you posted doesn't do anything useful. If you use Extended Events or SQL Server Profiler you'll see that EF already retrieves the IDs, for all inserted rows at once, by using `OUTPUT inserted.ID`. The trigger you used can only handle a single row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `OUTPUT` doesn't work properly on `INSTEAD OF` triggers as you get the wrong value back. https://dbfiddle.uk/3baql0kq